# I try to display the "Previous_reading" column in my database in Select Query where the database is already been used by Update Query

Tags: java, netbeans, wampserver

```
String v1=lbl_READING_NUMBER.getText();

        String v2=jTextField4.getText();

        try{

            String sql1 = "UPDATE reading set Previous_reading='"+v2+"' where

Reading_Number='"+v1+"'";

            ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);

            ps.executeUpdate();

        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }try{

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM reading WHERE Reading_number = ?";

            ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps1.setString(1, lbl_READING_NUMBER.getText());

            rs =ps1.executeQuery();

            String add1 = rs.getString("Previous_reading");

            lbl_READING_NUMBER.setText(add1);

        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }
```

The problem is when I execute this error says: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Answer (score 0):

```
rs =ps1.executeQuery();
```

after this line use

```
while (rs.next()){

  String add1 = rs.getString("Previous_reading");

}
```

java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set saying that pointer is before a row.
The next() moves the cursor  one row from its current position in the resultset. initialy it's position is before first row

Comment: @JhaezzJohn did you try ?